# Ubuntu 20.10. Cannot change the CPU scaling governor. It always goes back to "ondemand" after reboot

Tags: kernel, acpi, cpufreq, amd-ryzen, governor

I'm running Xubuntu 20.10. I'm trying to change the CPU scaling governor to "conservative". But it always goes back to "ondemand" after reboot.

I have a Ryzen 7 4800H. So, my CPU scaling driver is acpi-cpufreq. The kernel is `5.8.0-40-generic`

I tried with

```
# sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor conservative

# for GOVERNOR in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; \  ─╯
do \
    echo "conservative" | sudo tee $GOVERNOR; \
done

# sudo cpufreq-set -c 0 -g conservative
```

Without success in any case. That's very hot...

Do anybody knows what happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved editing the file `/etc/init.d/cpufrequtils`

And setting the variable `GOVERNOR="conservative"`

Note: Maybe you need to install `cpufrequtils` first

Comment: You need, additionally, to disable the `ondemand` service.